# Joomla issue when i enable SEO friendly URLs

Tags: url, joomla, seo

Please help me in the case I have searched a lot but didn't find any solution to my problem.
 I am facing an issue in a custom module which was built in **joomla 1.5** and now I have converted it into Joomla 3.4. When I enable SEO friendly URLs from global configuration view page of my module loads and then in the right sidebar it loads the whole page again. Which is causing the structure to break down.
 I don't know what to do. Please help me.

Please visit this URL for [SEO URL](http://www.soapboxapps.com/sheriff_appv4/en/real-estate/sheriffs-sale-webapp)

**Note:** Please use United States IP because this module uses an API to show Properties of United states on Google map. So it will only work for US IPs.

Thanks.